# Xamarin ui test failed to upload to appcenter error FORBIDEEN

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I am unable to test my  `xamarin ui test` in `appcenter` . `appcenter cli` returning this error

Error: Forbidden

The command is run is

```
appcenter test run uitest --app "Ethiopian-Airlines/Ethiopian-Airlines" --devices faa80d68 --app-path F:\Archive\com.ethiopianairlines.ethiopianairlines.apk  --test-series "launch-tests" --locale "en_US" --build-dir "C:\Users\DanielBas\Source\Repos\New folder\ETMobileAppUITest2\bin\Debug"

Preparing tests... done.
Validating arguments... done.
Creating new test run... failed.
Error: Forbidden
```

expected result creating new test done

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an API key from your account and add that as the `--token <your API key>` parameter to this command